# Create Circle and Marker on Click in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer, openlayers-2, circle

I want to create a marker and buffer around it with a given radius on map click event. Marker is displayed successfully but the polygon doesn't display. I guess there is problem in projection setting. Here are the projection settings for my map.

```
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG: 4326")
```

The event handler is as under.

```
    {
    radius = 3000;
    var sides = 50;

    if (!markersLayer) {
        markersLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
        bufferLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Buffer Layer");
        map.addLayer(markersLayer);
        map.addLayer(bufferLayer);
    }
    position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);

    //Create Marker
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(15, 15);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel( - (size.w / 2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconURL, size, offset);
    var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position, icon);
    // Cleanup Markers First
    markersLayer.clearMarkers();
    markersLayer.addMarker(marker);

    //Create Polygon
    var circle = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(position, radius, sides, 0);
    var circleFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(circle);
    var circleFeatures = [];
    circleFeatures.push(circleFeature);
    // Cleanup Features First
    bufferLayer.removeAllFeatures();
    bufferLayer.addFeatures(circleFeatures);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/new-OpenLayers-Geometry-Polygon-createRegularPolygon-td3969939.html

and

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon you need to hand over a point Geometry.

The coordinates of the point are not what the function expects.

You might refer to [OpenLayers - Cannot draw a circle using createRegularPolygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85041/openlayers-cannot-draw-a-circle-using-createregularpolygon) and [How to draw a polygon with preset length in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43379/how-to-draw-a-polygon-with-preset-length-in-openlayers/43386#43386) for working examples.

Comment: Thanks finally able to do it, just converted the position object to point using  var center_point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(position.lon, position.lat);